# Rendering 2D image using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc, glut, glew

I am trying to render a 2D image using OpenGL(for rendering) and DevIL(for loading image). But nothing gets rendered. Upon error checking I have found that OpenGL throws **Invalid Operation** on **wglMakeCurrent** call.

Following is my initialization function

```
void CImageMainView::InitializeOpenGL()
{
    m_pDC = new CClientDC(this);
    m_hDC = m_pDC->GetSafeHdc();

    SetupPixelFormat();
    m_hRC = ::wglCreateContext(m_hDC);

    BOOL ret = ::wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);
    if(!ret){
        printf("Error making current context\n");
    }
    printf("wglMakeCurrent ");
    CheckGLError();
    GetOpenGLExtendedInformation();
    ::wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    printf("wglMakeCurrent to null");
    CheckGLError();

    return;
}
```

SetupPixelFormat function looks like following

```
void CImageMainView::SetupPixelFormat()
{
    static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = 
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),  // size of this pfd
        1,                              // version number
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |            // support window
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |            // support OpenGL
        PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,               // double buffered
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                  // RGBA type
        24,                             // 24-bit color depth
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,               // color bits ignored
        0,                              // no alpha buffer
        0,                              // shift bit ignored
        0,                              // no accumulation buffer
        0, 0, 0, 0,                     // accum bits ignored
        32,                             // 32-bit z-buffer
        0,                              // no stencil buffer
        0,                              // no auxiliary buffer
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                 // main layer
        0,                              // reserved
        0, 0, 0                         // layer masks ignored
    };

    m_PixelFormat = ::ChoosePixelFormat(m_hDC, &pfd);
    ::SetPixelFormat(m_hDC, m_PixelFormat, &pfd);

    return;
}
```

and lastly the error checking function is

```
void CImageMainView::CheckGLError()
{

const GLenum err = glGetError();
printf("GLError: %s\n", gluErrorString(err));

}
```

I do have another View in my application that renders 3D stuff using OpenGL. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Which `wglMakeCurrent`, there are 2 in the code?

Comment: First one `BOOL ret = ::wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);`

Comment: Try with 24-bits depth buffer instead of 32. And verify you get m_PixelFormat > 0.

Comment: Still same. m_PixelFormat is greater than 0

Comment: Set m_hRC = 0, then create the context and now check m_hRC>0. I'm showing you how to do some debugging. Basically, verify each variable that has a role in the command that crashes.

Comment: You can have many different windows that render different things. You can NOT have two contexts for the same window

Comment: Use GLFW lib.It will make your life easier. Highly recommended for beginners.

Comment: Thanks @Ripi2 . Could you help me point out my options, if I want to render to two different views within the same window.

Comment: Just a matter of using two "camera" data with their different matrices. And if you want to see both views at once, side by side, then use different viewports (change origin and size inside that window). Overlapping views in the same window requires much more work.